# Определенную часть кода необходимо повторять каждые 3 минуты

Tags: python

Необходимо каждые 3 минуты отправлять такой запрос:

```
https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/ping?key=[your_secret_key]
```

при этом должен работать весь остальной код.

Comment: Создаете поток (`Thread`), в нем выполняете цикл (`while True`), в цикле отправляете запрос (`urilib`, `requests`, ...), делаете задержку на 3 минуты (`time.sleep`). Все понятно? :)

Comment: Можно екзампл малюсенький?)))

Comment: а то затуплю как всегда на элементарном

Comment: Ок, но в таких вопросах лучше всегда предоставляйте хоть какие-нибудь наработки, а то могут и закрыть, например как учебное задание -- т.е. когда есть просто задача от автора вопрос, а тот только просит решение (код)

Comment: Хорошо,спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так должно работать. Что здесь происходит, уже, вроде бы, объяснили в комментариях.

```py
import requests
import threading
import time

def req():
    url = "https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/ping?key=[your_secret_key]"

    while True:
        requests.get(url)  # Метод вместо GET можете поставить нужный
        time.sleep(60 * 3)  # Три раза по 60 секунд

t = threading.Thread(target=req)
t.start()
```

Comment: Все как по ТЗ (комментарию) :D

Comment: @gil9red Так и есть :)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы рекомендовал модуль `schedule` для планирования определённых задач.

***Пример:***

```py
import schedule
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import requests


def req(url):
    requests.get(url)


def scheduler():
    schedule.every(3).minutes.do(req, 'https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/ping?key=[your_secret_key]')

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(1)


def main():
    t = Thread(target=scheduler)
    t.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```